# Using CARTOframes to push to CARTO account

Tags: python, carto, jupyter-notebook, cartoframes

I am using CARTOframes to create and style a map that includes widgets. I'm able to push a Dataset to my Carto account and to publish and update a map, however I can't seem to get that published map to appear in my dashboard when I login to Cartodb. The goal is for people on my team to be able to make changes to a map either from a jupyter notebook using something like CARTOframes OR through logging on and using the Builder manually.

I have version `1.0b2` of CARTOframes installed and here is the code:

```
#setting credentials: 
set_default_credentials('https://{}.carto.com/'.format(username), api_key)

Creds = Credentials(username=username, api_key=api_key)

#to turn geopandas geodataframe into a carto Dataset: 

locations_data = Dataset(df)

#to create map

testmap = Map(Layer(locations_data,
          popup=Popup({'hover':[{'title':'service', "value":'$service_name'}]}),
            widgets=[
            default_widget(
                title='NYC Social Services Locations',
                description='Visualization of service sites for city-funded social services.',
                footer='Data source: SSSLD'
            ), 
            formula_widget(
                'count',
                is_global=True,
                footer='sites'
            ), 
            category_widget(
                'org_name',
                title='Provider Organization Name',
                description='Select an org to filter',
            )
            ]
         ) ) 

#to sync data with my account: 

testmap.sync_data('test_data')

#to publish map

testmap.publish('sssld_test_map_jupyter', maps_api_key=api_key, credentials=Creds)

#to update published map:

testmap.update_publication('sssld_test_map_gui', password=None, maps_api_key=api_key)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error after running your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visualizations created from CARTOframes are not shown yet in the dashboard, but that feature it's on the roadmap :)

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up!